# Why is using an internal attribute to filter objects considered OK, but when I use a map to filter based on attributes, it's considered a code smell?

Tags: java, object-oriented, code-smell

A long time ago I [asked](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/373390/using-a-variable-to-indicate-object-type) about using an enum to essentially use as a poor version of `instanceof` to make decisions about an object.

As stated in [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/373393/315575) answer:

> When your weapon types enum just mirrors the class hierarchy, then
>   this is a blatant violation of the DRY principle - you encode the same
>   information, the type of a weapon redundantly in two places - one
>   place is the class name itself, one place the enum. That's definitely
>   not just a code smell, that is bad code.

I then [wondered](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/379280/using-a-collection-with-attributes-to-check-and-make-decisions) about having a `List` or a `Map` that contained a collection of attributes that the object could hold and using a method, I would ask it about what attributes it contained and then proceed to work with that object.

Let's put the `Collection` idea aside for now, because I want to focus on another relatable problem.

In Clean Code, P.19 the following code snippet is given as a good example of well named methods and variables.

```
public List<Cell> getFlaggedCells(){
    List<Cell> flaggedCells = new ArrayList<Cell>();
    for(Cell cell : gameboard){
         if(cell.isFlagged()){
              flaggedCells.add(cell);
         }
    }
    return flaggedCells;
}
```

From this code snippet, we know a know that a `cell` contains a method that verifies if it's been flagged. In other words, we can ask the cell, are you flagged?

We then collect a `List` of flagged cells and return to the caller.

In my second question, I had the following code snippet:

```
public abstract class Weapon 
{
    private List<GameObjectAttributes> gOAttributes;

    // imagine a constructor :D.

    public final boolean containsAttribute(GameObjectAttributes attribute)
    {
        // determine if weapon contains a specific attribute. 
    }
}
```

A Wizard class might look like this:

```
public Wizard extends Character {

    private List<Weapons> weapons;

    public boolean tryAdd(Weapon weapon){
       if !(weapon.containsAttribute(WeaponType.LongBlade)){
          return weapons.add(weapon);
       }
       return false;     
    }
}
```

Much like the Clean Code snippet, I'm asking the object, do you contain a specific attribute, and if not, add it to the `weapons` collection.

As stated in this [link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/300080/when-are-enums-not-a-code-smell), using an `enum` to map polymorphic behaviors is a code smell, and rightfully so. The same warning is given in my second link at the top.

**Question:**

Why is the Clean Code sample considered fine, using an internal attribute to filter out objects, but when I use a map to filter based on attributes, it's considered code smell?

I'm **not** checking for a specific attribute and then calling a method to perform an action, I'm simply filtering, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: "Is [something] a code smell" is not an answerable question without including criteria that specifies what constitutes a "code smell."  Can you ask something more specific?  *Note:* don't replace "code smell" with some equally ambiguous tautology like "best practice."

Comment: @RobertHarvey - How about now?

Comment: "Acceptable" is a tautology.  It suffers the same problem as "best practice:" there's no way to determine what is acceptable or not without stating some criteria for evaluation.  You might be better off asking questions like *why.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Let's see if I can fix this. :D

Comment: @RobertHarvey - In a way I did state the criteria, the Clean Code sample is my criteria. Why is that sample considered fine, using an internal attribute to filter out objects, but when I use a map to filter based on attributes, it's all of a sudden considered code smell.

Comment: *That* sounds like an answerable question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I asked the question I stated in my comments. Feel free to edit it if it's unacceptable. :D.

Comment: In the answer you quoted, the author states that the use of an enum is a smell because it duplicates information that is already present in the class hierarchy.  Is your code breaking the same rule?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - No the CC sample isn't doing same. It's copied straight from the book, so I don't know the details of the class `Cell`. But the `Collection` attributes isn't mapping a class hierarchy. As a Weapon it can be described in certain ways, not all Swords might be able to be enchanted with a spell, so one `Sword` object might contain `enchantable` as an attribute, but that doesn't mean I check the attribute and then call `sword.enchant()` afterward.

Comment: Well, your code doesn't seem to be duplicating information that is already present in the class hierarchy either, so if your question is "does my code violate the principle laid out in the answer I quoted," I'd say no, it doesn't.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Nailed it! Thanks. If you have time, you can write it out as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Of course, if you actually have a `LongBlade` weapon in your class hierarchy, that's another story. :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I have `Sword` which is a subclass of `Weapon` but not `LongBladeSword` or `ShortBladeSword` you have to ask the object that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a problem with your code because there is a clear distinction between a **Weapon** and a **Weapon Attribute**.

Your `WeaponType` enum does not appear to directly model the weapon class hierarchy. `WeaponType.LongBlade` could be an attribute of `Kitana` or `Machete`.

You would obviously have different game behavior based on the type of weapon used, and I think you are correct in using weapon *attributes* to do this.

Maybe I'm missing something, but I think what you have is fine.